# Access Copy Value of Textbox on text change

Tags: forms, ms-access

I've a form in MS access that holds a subform showing records from a table. I've got a textbox whichs content is based on the selected record form the subset. If i select a record with id 2 then the value of the textbox is set to 2.

I want to copy the value of the textbox to another textbox of the form each time the value is changed.

The onChange eventhandler on the textbox bound to the subform does not trigger, neither does any other event when i select a record in the subform.

I'd either write some vba code to copy the text or use a makro.

Answer (score 1):

It probably is triggering if you change the field manually, e.g., this code works for me:

```
Private Sub Text0_Change()
    Text2.Value = Text0.Text
End Sub
```

(note `value` and `text`, as what you see in the field while you are editing it is not that same as the value of the field)

but not if you update it through VBA

> Setting the value of a control by using a macro or Visual Basic doesn't trigger this event for the control. You must type the data directly into the control, or set the control's Text property.
>   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821734.aspx

If the fields were named like in my example, I'd have whatever VB that updates `Text0` also update `Text2`

Comment: Since i don't enter anything in the textbox manually but show the selected id of the given record in the subform, this is not really helping. Is there any way to trigger the event manually on a change?

Comment: Not according to the link I included.  When the the event you have on the record change updates text0, you need it to also update text2. The VB update won't trigger it. Only you, typing in the GUI will.